# How to login and post to facebook wall in one dialog?

Tags: facebook, post, authentication, dialog, publish

I want to create a dialog that you can type your username and password
on the top and follow by a box where you can write things.And on the bottom is 
the publish button.that means you login and publish at the same time when you 
click the publish button.

I find many possible solutions but none is the answer I want.Is it possible to do?

Comment: Now I know I can't add username and password parameter to authorization page .(I already check developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed) If I don't use authorization page directly to post on wall, Is there any way, like create my own dialog or page, to combine login and publish to wall so I can do these two thing in one click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to push username and password parameter to facebook authorization page? If yes,facebook doesn't allow you to push username and password to the facebook authorization page...Correct me if i'm misunderstanding your situation.....

Comment: Now I know I can't add username and password parameter to authorization page .(I already check http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

If I don't use authorization page directly to post on wall, Is there any way, like create my own dialog or page, to combine login and publish to wall so I can do these two thing in one click ?

Comment: Actually,you can bypass the authorization page by get long-live access token from the user...If you want doing this,you still need only one authorization from the user...After that,you not need authorization from the user because you can publish to wall by using the access token...So, my suggestion is first time user need to authorize,then save the access token in database....